# Jhipster, AngularJS Client Side Model Rest One-To-Many

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have an application with two entities:

1. Employer (OneToMany with Employee)
2. Employee (ManyToOne with Employer)

**Employer Entity**:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

**Employee Entity:**

```
@ManyToOne
private Employer employer;
```

I know that the @JsonIgnore remove the possibility to fetch the list of employee from JSON. But I don't know what should I do to retrieve them.

### Client Side

**EmployerService.js**:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('Employer', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/employer/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    });
```

Should I create a new rest call to fetch them here, (with a new rest RequestMapping on the server side Rest Controller) and remove the @JsonIgnore?

Thank you.

Comment: are you able to solve this? if yes, could you please post the Angularjs code here. In jhipster website also I could not find that reference code.

Comment: Oh yes I solved that. I kept the @JsonIgnore because didn't want to have all data when not needed. But I implemented a Rest Call from the server part just to fetch the Employees. I also used a service to fetch them eagerly. I'll provide an example later. 
Create a service like that: http://jhipster.github.io/creating_a_service.html

Comment: Sqrt, could you please provide that example here?

Comment: Sorry for this big delay.. I wasn't available... Check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to resolve this, I used a service to retrieve the data in a Eager way.

Employer and Employee entities don't change.

**EmployerService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EmployerService {

    @Inject
    private EmployerRepository employerRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Set<Employee> getAllEmployeeForEmployerId(Long id) {
        Employer employer = employerRepository.findOne(id);
        if ( employer == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        employer.getEmployees().size(); //Fetch Eager on Lazily
        return employer.getEmployees();
    }

}
```

**In EmployerService.js add a new factory**

```
.factory('EmployerFactory', function($resource) {
        return {
            employees: $resource('api/employer/employee/:id'),
        }
```

And add the matching RestRequest in your controller.